# How to Export Power BI table data into sharepoint as a list

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, power-automate, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to export the Power BI data in to sharepoint as a list. I tried it by using the embedded sharep0int link and created a page in SharePoint and gave the link, but the data is showing as exactly it is showing in the power BI. I want the Power BI data to sit in a sharepoint as a list. Please check the below image of Power BI data and I want this data to be exported as lists in sharepoint. Please help.

[image]

Comment: how are you connected to that data source?

Comment: @user16187680  the data is coming from an excel file stored in a SharePoint.

Comment: then you should use Power Automate to convert the Excel table to a Sharepoint list, don't even think about Power BI in this scenario since it isn't necessary to use.